# Selecting elements based on data attribute's key values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a data attached to multiple div elements with the same class that I am trying to create a filter that show's / hide's them based on the data values assigned to the elements.  I need to drill down in the data to select the element based on the values of specific keys in the data.

Here is an example of one of the DIVs HTML

```
<div class="design-layouts" data-json-object="{"id":"1","layout_name":"Layout 1","side":"1","orientation":"Horizontal","has_image_area":"1","tags":"fresh, happy, test","categories":[{"id":"30","category_name":"aaa"},{"id":"1","category_name":"Agriculture & Farming"},{"id":"2","category_name":"Animals & Pet Care"},{"id":"3","category_name":"Art & Entertainment"},{"id":"34","category_name":"asdfasf"},{"id":"4","category_name":"Automotive & Transportation"},{"id":"5","category_name":"Beauty & Spa"},{"id":"6","category_name":"Business Services"},{"id":"10..."24","category_name":"Travel & Airline"}],"styles":[{"id":"1","style_name":"Abstract","parent_id":"0"},{"id":"2","style_name":"Bold","parent_id":"0"},{"id":"3","style_name":"Patriotic & Military","parent_id":"2"}],"colors":[{"id":"2","color_name":"Blue","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#009cff"},{"id":"4","color_name":"Brown","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#746451"},{"id":"1","color_name":"Grayscale","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#666666"},{"id":"3","color_name":"Red","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#ed1c24"}]}">
```

I need something along the lines of this that actually works though.

```
$( ".design-layouts[data-json-object='id':'1']" ).show(); 
$( ".design-layouts[data-json-object='color_name':'Red']" ).show();
```

Comment: `data-json-object="{"id":"1"}"` the double quotes can be a problem for you.

`data-json-object='{"id":"1"}'` use single quote for the attribute.

Comment: See what you mean, updated it in my code to be contained by single quotes.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I guess OP HTML is already escaped..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that the attribute is invalid, because it ends as of the first `"` within it. You'd have to convert all of the `"` in the attribute to `&quot;` (since attribute values are HTML text), or (easier) just use single quotes around the attribute value (provided there aren't any `'` in the value).

Then, you could use the "attribute contains" selector to do something close to what you want:

```js
$( ".design-layouts[data-json-object*='\"id\":\"1\"']" ).css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<div class="design-layouts" data-json-object='{"id":"1","layout_name":"Layout 1","side":"1","orientation":"Horizontal","has_image_area":"1","tags":"fresh, happy, test","categories":[{"id":"30","category_name":"aaa"},{"id":"1","category_name":"Agriculture & Farming"},{"id":"2","category_name":"Animals & Pet Care"},{"id":"3","category_name":"Art & Entertainment"},{"id":"34","category_name":"asdfasf"},{"id":"4","category_name":"Automotive & Transportation"},{"id":"5","category_name":"Beauty & Spa"},{"id":"6","category_name":"Business Services"},{"id":"10","category_name":"Travel & Airline"}],"styles":[{"id":"1","style_name":"Abstract","parent_id":"0"},{"id":"2","style_name":"Bold","parent_id":"0"},{"id":"3","style_name":"Patriotic & Military","parent_id":"2"}],"colors":[{"id":"2","color_name":"Blue","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#009cff"},{"id":"4","color_name":"Brown","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#746451"},{"id":"1","color_name":"Grayscale","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#666666"},{"id":"3","color_name":"Red","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#ed1c24"}]}'>Text in the div</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but the problem with that is it's purely textual.

Instead, you're likely to need to loop through matching elements, parse the JSON, and then decide what to do. You can do that with `filter`:

```js
$(".design-layouts[data-json-object]").filter(function() {
    return JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-json-object")).id == "1";
}).css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<div class="design-layouts" data-json-object='{"id":"1","layout_name":"Layout 1","side":"1","orientation":"Horizontal","has_image_area":"1","tags":"fresh, happy, test","categories":[{"id":"30","category_name":"aaa"},{"id":"1","category_name":"Agriculture & Farming"},{"id":"2","category_name":"Animals & Pet Care"},{"id":"3","category_name":"Art & Entertainment"},{"id":"34","category_name":"asdfasf"},{"id":"4","category_name":"Automotive & Transportation"},{"id":"5","category_name":"Beauty & Spa"},{"id":"6","category_name":"Business Services"},{"id":"10","category_name":"Travel & Airline"}],"styles":[{"id":"1","style_name":"Abstract","parent_id":"0"},{"id":"2","style_name":"Bold","parent_id":"0"},{"id":"3","style_name":"Patriotic & Military","parent_id":"2"}],"colors":[{"id":"2","color_name":"Blue","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#009cff"},{"id":"4","color_name":"Brown","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#746451"},{"id":"1","color_name":"Grayscale","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#666666"},{"id":"3","color_name":"Red","rgb_value":null,"hex_value":"#ed1c24"}]}'>Text in the div</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This lets you do much more sophisticated conditions around which elements to pick.

If you're going to do it more than once, it may well be useful once the elements are loaded to store the parsed result in jQuery's `data` cache:

```
$(".design-layouts[data-json-object]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("jsonObject", JSON.parse($this.attr("data-json-object")));
});
```

...and then you don't have to reparse later when processing them. (The name I chose above, `jsonObject`, is the name jQuery would automatically assign that `data-*` attribute. You could use a different name if you liked, though.)

Comment: Fix this part of the json `"10..."24"`.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Ah, is that the problem with the JSON? Thanks. I have to admit I didn't look closely at it, as it's a bit tangental to the question...

Comment: I have found it with jsonlint.com

Comment: Question TJ,  how would I select a category under that data.

Comment: "categories":[{"id":"30","category_name":"aaa"},{"id":"1","category_name":"Agriculture & Farming"}  it is 1 more layer deep

Answer (score 0):

I believe that something similar to this should do the trick:

```
$( '.design-layouts[data-json-object*=\""id":"1"\"]' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute object to get the data. EG

```
var dat = element.attributes["data-name-you-want"].value; 
                                            // gets the value stored in
                                            // the data attribute of an
                                            // element. You can also use 
                                            // dot notation and camel case
var dat element.attributes.dataNameYouWant.value;
```

So in your case you would

```
if(element.attributes["data-json-object"]){ // make sure the data is there
    // now parse it and look for the attribute you are after in the JSON
    if((JSON.parse(element.attributes["data-json-object"].value)).colour_name === 'red'){
        // you have found the colour red..
    }
}
```

Though I would wrap it all in a try catch because the JSON is hard to predict errors, you are using JQuery.